# win api readConsole()

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am trying to use Win API `ReadConsole(...)` and I want to pass in a delimiter char to halt the input from the console.
The below code works but it only stops reading the input on `\r\n`.
I would like it to stop reading the console input on `'.'` for instance.

```
void read(char *cIn, char delim)
{
    HANDLE hFile;
    DWORD charsRead;
    DWORD charsToRead = MAX_PATH;
    CONSOLE_READCONSOLE_CONTROL cReadControl;

    cReadControl.nLength = sizeof(CONSOLE_READCONSOLE_CONTROL);
    cReadControl.nInitialChars = 0;
    cReadControl.dwCtrlWakeupMask = delim;
    cReadControl.dwControlKeyState = NULL;

    DWORD lpMode;



//    char cIn[MAX_PATH];    //-- buffer to hold data from the console

    hFile = CreateFile("CONIN$", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                    FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL,
                    OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);

    GetConsoleMode(hFile,&lpMode);
//    lpMode &= ~ENABLE_LINE_INPUT;   //-- turns off this flag
//    SetConsoleMode(hFile, lpMode);  //-- set the mode with the new flag off

    bool read = ReadConsole(hFile, cIn, charsToRead * sizeof(TCHAR), &charsRead, &cReadControl);
    cIn[charsRead - 2] = '\0';
}
```

I know there are other easy ways to do this but I am just trying to understand some of the win api functions and how to use them.

Thank you.

Comment: if you want full control console input and got info about any key pressed, just when it pressed (but not wait for *VK_RETURN*) you need use *ReadConsoleInput* instead *ReadConsole*

Comment: @RbMm thanks, that is helpful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I saw this question and assumed it would be trivial, but spent the last 30 minutes trying to figure it out and finally have something.

That `dwCtrlWakeupMask` is pretty poorly documented in `CONSOLE_READCONSOLE_CONTROL`. MSDN says "A user-defined control character used to signal that the read is complete.", but why is it called `mask`? Why is it a `ULONG` instead of a `TCHAR` or something like that? I tried feeding it chars and wchars and nothing happened, so there must be more to the story.

I took to the web searching for that particular variable and found this link:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-codereviews/KSp37ITmcUg It is a random Go library coder asking for help and the answer is that tab is `1 << '\t'`. I tried it, and it works!

So, for future web searchers, `dwCtrlWakeupMask` is a bitmask of ASCII control characters that will cause `ReadConsole` to return. You can `|` together as many `1 << ctrl_char`s as you like... but it cannot be arbitrary characters, since it is a bitmask in a 32 bit value, only the chars 1-31 (inclusive) are possible (this group btw is called control characters, it includes things like tab, backspace, bell; things that do not represent printable characters per se).

Thus, this mask:

```
cReadControl.dwCtrlWakeupMask = (1 << '\t') | (1 << 0x08);
```

Will cause `ReadConsole` to return when tab (`\t`) OR when backspace (`0x08`) is pressed.

The characters represented by `ctrl+ some_ascii_value` are the number of that letter in the english alphabet, starting at a == 1. So, `ctrl+d` is `4`, and `ctrl+z` is `26`.

Therefore, this will return when the user hits `ctrl+d` or `ctrl+z`:

```
cReadControl.dwCtrlWakeupMask = (1 << 4) | (1 << 26);
```

Note that the Linux terminal driver also returns on `read` when the user hits `ctrl+d` so this might be a nice compatibility thing.

I believe the point of this argument is to allow easier tab-completion in processed input mode; otherwise, you'd have to turn processed input off and process keys one by one to do that. Now you don't have to.... though tbh, I still prefer taking my input with `ReadConsoleInput` for interactive programs since you get much better control over it all.

But while there are a lot of other ways to do what you want - and using `.` as a delimiter is impossible here, since it has a value >= 32, so you need to do it yourself... understanding what this does is interesting to me anyway, and there's scarce resources on the web so I'm writing this up just for future reference.

Note that this does not appear to work in `wineconsole` so be sure you are on a real Windows box to test it out.

Now, `dwControlKeyState` is actually set BY the function. Your value passed in is ignored (at least as far as I can tell), but you can inspect it for the given flags when the function returns. So, for example, after calling `ReadConsole` and hitting the key, it will be 32 if your numlock was on. It will be 48 is numlock was on and you pressed shift+tab (and had numlock on). So you test it after the function returns.

I typically like MSDN docs but IMO they completely dropped the ball on explaining this parameter!

Comment: @ilw indeed, space is code 32 so slightly too big to fit in there.

Comment: I am coming back to using this function and want to write up more details of how it works. When you pass a CONSOLE_READCONSOLE_CONTROL struct, the `nInitialChars` member keeps some of the input buffer in the console's edit buffer. When it returns, the input will *replace* the character at the cursor location in the buffer with the char, and keep the rest of the editing line in there. You can scan for that and edit the buffer, then call again and set that `nInitialChars` member to keep for next thing. Though if you tab complete in the middle of a line, you cannot keep the cursor in the middle.

Comment: Can any one help me with why ReadConsole, WriteConsole, ReadFile(console_in), WriteFile(console_out) fail if request buf size is too big, such as 65000 bytes? I expected it to just give back as much as it could read or write. And the posix alternatives _write and _read work perfectly.

Comment: @JaveneCPPMcGowan the docs don't say but i have seen people report there's a 64 kb limit on some of the functions. Since it is wide chars, that means 32k elements max may be all that supported. But you can definitely use a buffer bigger than is available - that's how you normally do it, just like on posix. Just try a smaller buffer and see what happens.

Comment: @Adam D. Ruppe thanks. Doesnt solve my problem but thanks anyhow? My problem is the need for consistency. MSDN should have documented such error. And the fact that others arent complaining means something is out of wack. Obviously the posix functions are designed without these limitations. Probably opening the terminal in posix mode will solve my problem.

Comment: @Adam D. Ruppe t GetLastError() == 8. Only Error Code I see matching it is ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY. Opening Console with FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING|FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH, or FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH doesn't solve the problem my assumed out of memory. Then FILE_FLAG_POSIX_SEMANTICS didnt solve my large read write console problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will find this code ridiculous. It is most likely the only way to do this. If you have to adapt to use ReadFile later it is the only way that doesn't consume more input.

Most of the time you don't really want ReadConsole at all you want ReadFile on the standard input handle, but I digress.

```
char *cInptr = cIn;
do {
    bool read = ReadConsole(hFile, cInptr, sizeof(TCHAR), &charsRead, &cReadControl);
    if (read) cInptr += charsRead;
} while (read && charsRead > 0 && cInptr[-1] && cInptr[-1] != '.');
```

I might have too many tests in the loop due to being paranoid. I'm not inclined to look up all predicates to determine which are implied by the contract of ReadConsole.

Comment: ReadConsole has an important advantage over ReadFile: it works to read unicode characters. Using ReadConsoleW and WriteConsoleW you get wide chars and thus avoid all the trouble with code pages you have with the others.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe: In my experience, when this problem comes up, stdin is usually connected to a pipe. Perhaps not in this case.

Comment: Note, however, that ReadFile is a binary reader, and its counts are bytes, as opposed to characters for ReadConsole.